# How to make a sunburst plot in R or Python?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, data-visualization, sunburst-diagram

So far I have been unable to find an R library that can create a sunburst plot like those by [John Stasko](http://www.cc.gatech.edu/gvu/ii/sunburst/). Anyone knows how to accomplish that in R or Python?

[image: Sunburst]

Comment: The rectangular equivalent of these known as "treemaps" are quite popular. You might have better luck if you search for "circular treemaps" or similar.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Python version of sunburst diagram using matplotlib bars in polar projection:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def sunburst(nodes, total=np.pi * 2, offset=0, level=0, ax=None):
    ax = ax or plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')

    if level == 0 and len(nodes) == 1:
        label, value, subnodes = nodes[0]
        ax.bar([0], [0.5], [np.pi * 2])
        ax.text(0, 0, label, ha='center', va='center')
        sunburst(subnodes, total=value, level=level + 1, ax=ax)
    elif nodes:
        d = np.pi * 2 / total
        labels = []
        widths = []
        local_offset = offset
        for label, value, subnodes in nodes:
            labels.append(label)
            widths.append(value * d)
            sunburst(subnodes, total=total, offset=local_offset,
                     level=level + 1, ax=ax)
            local_offset += value
        values = np.cumsum([offset * d] + widths[:-1])
        heights = [1] * len(nodes)
        bottoms = np.zeros(len(nodes)) + level - 0.5
        rects = ax.bar(values, heights, widths, bottoms, linewidth=1,
                       edgecolor='white', align='edge')
        for rect, label in zip(rects, labels):
            x = rect.get_x() + rect.get_width() / 2
            y = rect.get_y() + rect.get_height() / 2
            rotation = (90 + (360 - np.degrees(x) % 180)) % 360
            ax.text(x, y, label, rotation=rotation, ha='center', va='center') 

    if level == 0:
        ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
        ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
        ax.set_axis_off()
```

Example, how this function can be used:

```
data = [
    ('/', 100, [
        ('home', 70, [
            ('Images', 40, []),
            ('Videos', 20, []),
            ('Documents', 5, []),
        ]),
        ('usr', 15, [
            ('src', 6, [
                ('linux-headers', 4, []),
                ('virtualbox', 1, []),

            ]),
            ('lib', 4, []),
            ('share', 2, []),
            ('bin', 1, []),
            ('local', 1, []),
            ('include', 1, []),
        ]),
    ]),
]

sunburst(data)
```

[image: python matplotlib sunburst diagram]

Comment: This is the most elegant answer! Love the recursion.

Comment: Simple to process, extensible, no extra libraries needed; pure genius. This deserves more upvotes.

Comment: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373  can this kind of interactive-zoomable viz be done in R?

Answer (score 35):

You can even build an interactive version quite easily with R now:

```
# devtools::install_github("timelyportfolio/sunburstR")

library(sunburstR)
# read in sample visit-sequences.csv data provided in source
# https://gist.github.com/kerryrodden/7090426#file-visit-sequences-csv
sequences <- read.csv(
  system.file("examples/visit-sequences.csv",package="sunburstR")
  ,header=F
  ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sunburst(sequences)
```

[image]

...and when you move your mouse above it, the magic happens:

[image]

**Edit**
The official site of this package can be found here (with many examples!): https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR

Hat Tip to @timelyportfolio who created this impressive piece of code!

Comment: @Dror: This might interest you :-)

Comment: thanks for adding the update.  I of course much prefer the interactive version.  Anybody looking please feel free to offer feedback, ideas, criticism, use cases, examples at https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR

Comment: @timelyportfolio: Thank you, I added the link to the answer :-)

Comment: when drilling down , Is there a way to control the length and sequence of events ? in your example there are 6 events in the sequence going from `home->product->product->product->product->account` . I have 24 events in the sequence. Is it possible to dynamically extend the sequence displayed on top, without any words getting cut off? thank you.

Comment: how do I split the legend into two columns? to ensure that all the labels are displayed properly?

Comment: @kRazzyR: I am not the author of the code. Best would be to put your questions here: https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR/issues

Comment: @timelyportfolio: I am working to replicate SunburstR viz & have read extensively about it, First Thank you for all the work, its ttruly great.
However, I could not find one thing & that is how to make data in the format that sunburst() takes in. I mean could you share an example with iris or mtcars or any other r inbuild dataset & how that was converted to sequence & inputted to sunburst

Answer (score 14):

You can create something along the lines of a sunburst plot using `geom_tile` from the `ggplot2` package. Let's first create some random data:

```
require(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
require(plyr)
dat = data.frame(expand.grid(x = 1:10, y = 1:10),
                 z = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 100, replace = TRUE))
```

And then create the raster plot. Here, the `x` axis in the plot is coupled to the `x` variable in `dat`, the `y` axis to the `y` variable, and the fill of the pixels to the `z` variable. This yields the following plot:

```
p = ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = z)) + geom_tile() 
print(p)
```

[image]

The `ggplot2` package supports all kinds of coordinate transformations, one of which takes one axis and projects it on a circle, i.e. polar coordinates:

```
p + coord_polar()
```

[image]

This roughly does what you need, now you can tweak `dat` to get the desired result.

Comment: I admit it works, but it does not look quite production quality. I get irregular white spaces in between the rings. But thanks for the effort!

Comment: I do not have the irregular white spaces, at least not in the png I posted above. Do you have the latest ggplot2 version?

Comment: I just updated it to be sure, and I still have that. I'm using a Windows machine.

Comment: The problem probably goes away when you dump the figure to file.

Comment: Would you mind spoonfeeding the ggplot2 steps to make this graph? I'm still finding it hard to understand how the dat datatable is represented in the ribbon.

Comment: I quite heavily edited my code, I found that my original answer was suboptimal or even wrong. See the new code, if you still have trouble understanding it, drop a comment.

Comment: That's a polar grid, not a sunburst !

Comment: @PAC could you explain why that is a problem.  In my understanding a sunburst plot is a polar plot, the resulting plot looks fine to me.

Comment: In the sunburst, the area of the cells are proportional to the data. In the polar grid, the area of the cells isn't data-driven and the data is visualized using colors (see this example : [link](http://askmedia.fr/blog/askmedia-sur-paris-match-le-low-cost-est-il-vraiment-moins-cher/).

Comment: Ok, I see. My answer only provides a first step towards what the OP wants, so I'll leave it like this. Maybe you could expand my answer or add one of your own?

Comment: Late to the party, but you could make a ggplot2 sunburst using `geom_bar`. I'll add an answer below.

Answer (score 7):

There is a package called `ggsunburst`. Sadly is not in CRAN but you can install it from Github: [didacs/ggsunburst](https://github.com/didacs/ggsunburst).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `ggplot2` sunburst with two layers.

The basic idea is to just make a different bar for each layer, and make the bars wider for the outer layers. I also messed with the x-axis to make sure there's no hole in the middle of the inner pie chart. You can thus control the look of the sunburst by changing the width and x-axis values.

```
library(ggplot2)

# make some fake data
df <- data.frame(
    'level1'=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c'), 
    'level2'=c('a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'b1', 'b2', 'c1', 'c2', 'c3'), 
    'value'=c(.025, .05, .027, .005, .012, .014, .1, .03, .18))

# sunburst plot
ggplot(df, aes(y=value)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=level1, x=0), width=.5, stat='identity') + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=level2, x=.25), width=.25, stat='identity') + 
    coord_polar(theta='y')
```

[image]

The only disadvantage this has compared to sunburst-specific software is that it assumes you want the outer layers to be collectively exhaustive (i.e. no gaps). "Partially exhaustive" outer layers (like in some of the other examples) are surely possible but more complicated.

For completeness, here it is cleaned up with nicer formatting and labels:

```
library(data.table)

# compute cumulative sum for outer labels
df <- data.table(df)
df[, cumulative:=cumsum(value)-(value/2)]

# store labels for inner circle
inner_df <- df[, c('level1', 'value'), with=FALSE]
inner_df[, level1_value:=sum(value), by='level1']
inner_df <- unique(text_df[, c('level1', 'level1_value'), with=FALSE])
inner_df[, cumulative:=cumsum(level1_value)]
inner_df[, prev:=shift(cumulative)]
inner_df[is.na(prev), position:=(level1_value/2)]
inner_df[!is.na(prev), position:=(level1_value/2)+prev]

colors <- c('#6a3d9a', '#1F78B4', '#33A02C', '#3F146D', '#56238D', '#855CB1', '#AD8CD0', '#08619A', '#3F8DC0', '#076302', '#1B8416', '#50B74B')
colorNames <- c(unique(as.character(df$level1)), unique(as.character(df$level2)))
names(colors) <- colorNames

ggplot(df, aes(y=value, x='')) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=level2, x=.25), width=.25, stat='identity') + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=level1, x=0), width=.5, stat='identity') + 
    geom_text(data=inner_df, aes(label=level1, x=.05, y=position)) + 
    coord_polar(theta='y') + 
    scale_fill_manual('', values=colors) +
    theme_minimal() + 
    guides(fill=guide_legend(ncol=1)) +
    labs(title='') + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks=NULL) + 
    scale_y_continuous(breaks=df$cumulative, labels=df$level2, 5) + 
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.title.y=element_blank(), panel.border=element_blank(), panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are only a couple of libraries that I know of that do this natively:

- The [Javascript Infovis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.com/jit/) (jit) ([example](http://philogb.github.com/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Sunburst/example2.html)).
- [D3.js](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/sunburst.html)
- OCaml's [Simple Plot Tool](http://code.google.com/p/caml-spt/) (SPT).

Neither of these are in Python or R, but getting a python/R script to write out a simple JSON file that can be loaded by either of the javascript libraries should be pretty achievable.

Comment: Is there any update to this answer, over 2 years later?

Answer (score 3):

Since jbkunst mentioned ggsunburst, here I post an example for reproducing the sunburst by sirex.

It is not exactly the same because in ggsunburst the angle of a node is equal to the sum of the angles of its children nodes.

```
# install ggsunburst package
if (!require("ggplot2")) install.packages("ggplot2")
if (!require("rPython")) install.packages("rPython")
install.packages("http://genome.crg.es/~didac/ggsunburst/ggsunburst_0.0.9.tar.gz", repos=NULL, type="source")
library(ggsunburst)

# dataframe
# each row corresponds to a node in the hierarchy
# parent and node are required, the rest are optional attributes
# the attributes correspond to the node, not its parent
df <- read.table(header = T, sep = ",", text = "
parent,node,size,color,dist
,/,,B,1
/,home,,D,1
home,Images, 40,E,1
home,Videos, 20,E,1
home,Documents, 5,E,1
/,usr,,D,1
usr,src,,A,1
src,linux-headers, 4,C,1.5
src,virtualbox, 1,C,1.5
usr,lib, 4,A,1
usr,share, 2,A,1
usr,bin, 1,A,1
usr,local, 1,A,1
usr,include, 1,A,1
")

write.table(df, 'df.csv', sep = ",", row.names = F)

# compute coordinates from dataframe
# "node_attributes" is used to pass the attributes other than "size" and "dist", 
# which are special attributes that alter the dimensions of the nodes
sb <- sunburst_data('df.csv', sep = ",", type = "node_parent", node_attributes = "color")

# plot
sunburst(sb, node_labels = T, node_labels.min = 10, rects.fill.aes = "color") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1", guide = F)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using R and [plotly](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly) (based on my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57395424/how-to-format-data-for-plotly-sunburst-diagram/58481176#58481176)):

```
library(datasets)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

as.sunburstDF <- function(DF, valueCol = NULL){
  require(data.table)
  
  colNamesDF <- names(DF)
  
  if(is.data.table(DF)){
    DT <- copy(DF)
  } else {
    DT <- data.table(DF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  
  DT[, root := names(DF)[1]]
  colNamesDT <- names(DT)
  
  if(is.null(valueCol)){
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", colNamesDF))
  } else {
    setnames(DT, valueCol, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", setdiff(colNamesDF, valueCol), "values"))
  }
  
  hierarchyCols <- setdiff(colNamesDT, "values")
  hierarchyList <- list()
  
  for(i in seq_along(hierarchyCols)){
    currentCols <- colNamesDT[1:i]
    if(is.null(valueCol)){
      currentDT <- unique(DT[, ..currentCols][, values := .N, by = currentCols], by = currentCols)
    } else {
      currentDT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by=currentCols, .SDcols = "values"]
    }
    setnames(currentDT, length(currentCols), "labels")
    hierarchyList[[i]] <- currentDT
  }
  
  hierarchyDT <- rbindlist(hierarchyList, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  
  parentCols <- setdiff(names(hierarchyDT), c("labels", "values", valueCol))
  hierarchyDT[, parents := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(all(is.na(x)), yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[!is.na(x)], sep = ":", collapse = " - "))}), .SDcols = parentCols]
  hierarchyDT[, ids := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " - ")}), .SDcols = c("parents", "labels")]
  hierarchyDT[, c(parentCols) := NULL]
  return(hierarchyDT)
}

DF <- as.data.table(Titanic)
setcolorder(DF, c("Survived", "Class", "Sex", "Age", "N"))
sunburstDF <- as.sunburstDF(DF, valueCol = "N")

# Sunburst
plot_ly(data = sunburstDF, ids = ~ids, labels= ~labels, parents = ~parents, values= ~values, type='sunburst', branchvalues = 'total')

# Treemap
# plot_ly(data = sunburstDF, ids = ~ids, labels= ~labels, parents = ~parents, values= ~values, type='treemap', branchvalues = 'total')
```

[image: result]

Some additional information can be found [here](https://plotly.com/r/sunburst-charts/).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use plotly Sunburst on python as well as seen [here](https://plotly.com/python/sunburst-charts/)

The same inputs can be used to create Icicle and Treemap graphs (supported too by plotly) which might also suit your needs.