# How to format data for plotly sunburst diagram

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly, sunburst-diagram

I'm trying to make an sunburst diagram using Plotly via R. I'm struggling with the data model required for the hierarchy, both in terms of conceptualizing how it works, and seeing if there are any easy ways to transform a regular dataframe, with columns representing different hierarchical levels, into the format needed.

I've looked at examples for plotly sunburst charts in R, e.g., [here](https://plot.ly/r/sunburst-charts/), and seen the [reference page](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#sunburst) but don't totally get the model for data formatting.

```r
# Create some fake data - say ownership and land use data with acreage
df <- data.frame(ownership=c(rep("private", 3), rep("public",3),rep("mixed", 3)), 
                 landuse=c(rep(c("residential", "recreation", "commercial"),3)),
                 acres=c(108,143,102, 300,320,500, 37,58,90))

# Just try some quick pie charts of acreage by landuse and ownership
plot_ly(data=df, labels= ~landuse, values= ~acres, type='pie')
plot_ly(data=df, labels= ~ownership, values= ~acres, type='pie')

# This doesn't render anything... not that I'd expect it to given the data format doesn't seem to match what's needed, 
# but this is what I'd intuitively expect to work
plot_ly(data=df, labels= ~landuse, parents = ~ownership, values= ~acres, type='sunburst')
```

It would be helpful, given the example code above, or similar, to see how one might go from the data (`df`) to the format required for the plotly sunburst diagram.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are absolutely right, compared to the rest of the intuitiv usage of plotly's R API preparing data for a sunburst (or treemap) chart is rather annoying.

I had the same problem and wrote a function based on `library(data.table)` to prepare the data, accepting two different `data.frame` input formats.

The format required to generate a sunburst plot using data similarly structured as yours can be seen [here](https://plot.ly/r/sunburst-charts/) under the section **Sunburst with Repeated Labels**.

For your example it should look like this:

```
         labels values         parents                           ids
 1:       total   1658            <NA>                         total
 2:     private    353           total               total - private
 3:      public   1120           total                total - public
 4:       mixed    185           total                 total - mixed
 5: residential    108 total - private total - private - residential
 6:  recreation    143 total - private  total - private - recreation
 7:  commercial    102 total - private  total - private - commercial
 8: residential    300  total - public  total - public - residential
 9:  recreation    320  total - public   total - public - recreation
10:  commercial    500  total - public   total - public - commercial
11: residential     37   total - mixed   total - mixed - residential
12:  recreation     58   total - mixed    total - mixed - recreation
13:  commercial     90   total - mixed    total - mixed - commercial
```

Here is the code to get there:

```
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

DF <- data.table(ownership=c(rep("private", 3), rep("public",3),rep("mixed", 3)),
                 landuse=c(rep(c("residential", "recreation", "commercial"),3)),
                 acres=c(108, 143, 102, 300, 320, 500, 37, 58, 90))

as.sunburstDF <- function(DF, value_column = NULL, add_root = FALSE){
  require(data.table)
  
  colNamesDF <- names(DF)
  
  if(is.data.table(DF)){
    DT <- copy(DF)
  } else {
    DT <- data.table(DF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  
  if(add_root){
    DT[, root := "Total"]  
  }
  
  colNamesDT <- names(DT)
  hierarchy_columns <- setdiff(colNamesDT, value_column)
  DT[, (hierarchy_columns) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = hierarchy_columns]
  
  if(is.null(value_column) && add_root){
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", colNamesDF))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && !add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c(setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  }
  
  hierarchyList <- list()
  
  for(i in seq_along(hierarchy_columns)){
    current_columns <- colNamesDT[1:i]
    if(is.null(value_column)){
      currentDT <- unique(DT[, ..current_columns][, values := .N, by = current_columns], by = current_columns)
    } else {
      currentDT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by=current_columns, .SDcols = "values"]
    }
    setnames(currentDT, length(current_columns), "labels")
    hierarchyList[[i]] <- currentDT
  }
  
  hierarchyDT <- rbindlist(hierarchyList, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  
  parent_columns <- setdiff(names(hierarchyDT), c("labels", "values", value_column))
  hierarchyDT[, parents := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(all(is.na(x)), yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[!is.na(x)], sep = ":", collapse = " - "))}), .SDcols = parent_columns]
  hierarchyDT[, ids := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " - ")}), .SDcols = c("parents", "labels")]
  hierarchyDT[, c(parent_columns) := NULL]
  return(hierarchyDT)
}


sunburstDF <- as.sunburstDF(DF, value_column = "acres", add_root = TRUE)

plot_ly(data = sunburstDF, ids = ~ids, labels= ~labels, parents = ~parents, values= ~values, type='sunburst', branchvalues = 'total')
```

[image: result]

Here is an example for the second `data.frame` format accepted by the function (`value_column = NULL`, because it is calculated from the data):

```
DF2 <- data.frame(sample(LETTERS[1:3], 100, replace = TRUE),
                  sample(LETTERS[4:6], 100, replace = TRUE),
                  sample(LETTERS[7:9], 100, replace = TRUE),
                  sample(LETTERS[10:12], 100, replace = TRUE),
                  sample(LETTERS[13:15], 100, replace = TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

plot_ly(data = as.sunburstDF(DF2, add_root = TRUE), ids = ~ids, labels= ~labels, parents = ~parents, values= ~values, type='sunburst', branchvalues = 'total')
```

Please also see library([sunburstR](https://github.com/timelyportfolio/sunburstR)) as an alternative.

---

**Edit:** Added a benchmark regarding the dplyr based `count_to_sunburst()` function from `library(plotme)` (see below), which on my system is around 5 times slower than the `data.table` version.

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
        plotme 50.4618 53.09425 60.92404 55.37815 63.62315 122.3842   100
 ismirsehregal  8.6553 10.28870 12.63881 11.53760 12.26620 108.2025   100
```

---

Code to reproduce the benchmark:

```
# devtools::install_github("yogevherz/plotme")

library(microbenchmark)
library(plotme)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
library(plotly)

DF <- data.frame(ownership=c(rep("private", 3), rep("public",3),rep("mixed", 3)),
                 landuse=c(rep(c("residential", "recreation", "commercial"),3)),
                 acres=c(108, 143, 102, 300, 320, 500, 37, 58, 90))

as.sunburstDF <- function(DF, value_column = NULL, add_root = FALSE){
  require(data.table)
  
  colNamesDF <- names(DF)
  
  if(is.data.table(DF)){
    DT <- copy(DF)
  } else {
    DT <- data.table(DF, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  }
  
  if(add_root){
    DT[, root := "Total"]  
  }
  
  colNamesDT <- names(DT)
  hierarchy_columns <- setdiff(colNamesDT, value_column)
  DT[, (hierarchy_columns) := lapply(.SD, as.factor), .SDcols = hierarchy_columns]
  
  if(is.null(value_column) && add_root){
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", colNamesDF))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && !add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c(setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  } else if(!is.null(value_column) && add_root) {
    setnames(DT, value_column, "values", skip_absent=TRUE)
    setcolorder(DT, c("root", setdiff(colNamesDF, value_column), "values"))
  }
  
  hierarchyList <- list()
  
  for(i in seq_along(hierarchy_columns)){
    current_columns <- colNamesDT[1:i]
    if(is.null(value_column)){
      currentDT <- unique(DT[, ..current_columns][, values := .N, by = current_columns], by = current_columns)
    } else {
      currentDT <- DT[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm = TRUE), by=current_columns, .SDcols = "values"]
    }
    setnames(currentDT, length(current_columns), "labels")
    hierarchyList[[i]] <- currentDT
  }
  
  hierarchyDT <- rbindlist(hierarchyList, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  
  parent_columns <- setdiff(names(hierarchyDT), c("labels", "values", value_column))
  hierarchyDT[, parents := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){fifelse(all(is.na(x)), yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[!is.na(x)], sep = ":", collapse = " - "))}), .SDcols = parent_columns]
  hierarchyDT[, ids := apply(.SD, 1, function(x){paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse = " - ")}), .SDcols = c("parents", "labels")]
  hierarchyDT[, c(parent_columns) := NULL]
  return(hierarchyDT)
}

microbenchmark(plotme = {
  DF %>% 
    rename(n = acres) %>% 
    count_to_sunburst()
}, ismirsehregal = {
  plot_ly(data = as.sunburstDF(DF, value_column = "acres", add_root = TRUE), ids = ~ids, labels= ~labels, parents = ~parents, values= ~values, type='sunburst', branchvalues = 'total')  
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the function! It helps a lot! However, I think there is an extra `f` in the `ifelse` statement - `function(x){fifelse(all(is.na(x))`.

Comment: `fifelse()` is a function from `library(data.table)` - that additional `f` stands for "fast" - please see [this](https://rdatatable.gitlab.io/data.table/reference/fifelse.html)

Comment: Somehow I'm getting this error `Error in fifelse(all(is.na(x)), yes = NA_character_, no = paste(x[!is.na(x)],  : could not find function "fifelse" ` if I don't remove the `f`.

Comment: You might need to update your `data.table` package. `fifelse` is [available since](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#new-features-2) `data.table` version 1.12.4.

Comment: This is a fantastic function!

Answer (score 3):

There's the `plotme` package especially for this task:

```
library(plotme)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename(n = acres) %>% 
  count_to_sunburst()
```

[image]

To install the package run:

```
devtools::install_github("yogevherz/plotme")
```

More on the package [here](https://github.com/yogevherz/plotme).

Comment: I just added a benchmark regarding your dplyr based `count_to_sunburst()` function, which on my system is around 5 times slower than the above `data.table` version.

Comment: @yogevmh Is there a way to get the prepared-for-plotting data using a function in the `plotme` package?  I've got tons of plot customization I'll need to do, but would find a function I can call to get my count data prepped very helpful!