# Javascript sorting for a SunburstR Graph

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, sunburst-diagram

I've recently updated my SunburstR package in R to the 2.0 Version and suddenly the sorting of the slices (by size, descending, clockwise) does not happen automatically as it used to. Any R & JS/d3.js expert around to help me implement a custom JS sortFunction or say how to solve the problem? For reproduction purposes:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(sunburstR)
b = read.csv(
   file = paste0(
   "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rileycrane/",
   "92a2c36eb932b4f99e51/raw/",
   "a0212b4ca8043af47ec82369aa5f023530279aa3/visit-sequences.csv"
 ),header=FALSE
,stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

sequence_json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(
  system.file("examples/visit-sequences.json",package="sunburstR"),
  simplifyDataFrame = FALSE
)
sunburst(sequence_json)
```

sunburst function provides a sortFunction parameeter where one can write custom JS, like in:

```
sunburst(df,
     # create a trivial sort function
     sortFunction = htmlwidgets::JS('function(x) {return x;}'))
```

Thanks!

PS result:
[image: Not sorted]

**How it used to look like (notice the order of slices):**

[Sunburst in ealier versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32888561/6761066)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [example](https://bl.ocks.org/timelyportfolio/7afb4a361036b1da34c6234c9970ccd2) sorting alphabetically will help.

As another example, here is how we could sort each node from largest to smallest count.

```
library(sunburstR)

sequence_json <- jsonlite::fromJSON(
  system.file("examples/visit-sequences.json",package="sunburstR"),
  simplifyDataFrame = FALSE
)

sunburst(
  sequence_json,
  sortFunction = htmlwidgets::JS(
    "
function(a,b) {
  // sort by count descending
  //   unlike the other example using data.name, value is at the top level of the object
  return b.value - a.value
}
"    
  )
)
```

Most of the attributes will become prepended by `.data`.

[image: screenshot of json data]

[image: screenshot of node data]

It might be helpful to set a `debugger` in the sortFunction and open the widget with developer tools in Chrome and Firefox to see what you are working with.

Comment: Wow from the creator himself :) Thank you so much! I've actually been using rend2b which looks amazing, but the valueField doesn't seem to pick up when I use "size" as a param (which is also the default param).

Comment: Correction - I've now noticed that the valueField does something else. What I lack is sorting of the slices in sund2b.

Comment: sorting on the `sund2b` will be a little trickier, but https://github.com/d2bjs/d2b/issues/17 shows that it can be done.