# Follow up of : How to make a sunburst plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, sunburst-diagram

I'm new to R and I would have asked the question directly in the comments but I don't have the reputation yet :D

Basically, I wanted to do a sunburst diagram like dmp suggested in this thread: [How to make a sunburst plot in R or Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926779/how-to-make-a-sunburst-plot-in-r-or-python)

However, my dataframe looks more like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
    'level1'=c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'), 
    'level2'=c('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'AA', 'BB'), 
    'value'=c(12.5, 12.5, 75, 50, 25, 25, 36, 64))
```

So when I plot the sunburst plot as follows:

```
ggplot(df, aes(y=value)) +
    geom_bar(aes(fill=level1, x=0), width=.5, stat='identity') + 
    geom_bar(aes(fill=level2, x=.25), width=.25, stat='identity') + 
    coord_polar(theta='y')
```

ggplot groups the level2 together (so adds all AA together, then all BB and all CC) instead of leaving each within their level1. How do I prevent that?

Thank you very much in advance,

Nath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding a row ID column to your data frame & use it explicitly as a grouping variable. This prevents `ggplot()` from grouping the bars by the `fill` aesthetic:

```
library(dplyr)

ggplot(df %>% mutate(id = seq(1, n())), 
       aes(y = value, group = id)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = level1, x = 0), width = .5) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = level2, x = .25), width = .25) +
  coord_polar(theta = 'y')
```

[image: plot]