# Plotly: How to display legends for a sunburst diagram?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I'm trying to display legends alongside my plotly sunburst plot.

Example sunburst:

```
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['day', 'time'], values='total_bill')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Ideally, I would like to display the inner or outer values and respective colors inside the black rectangle.

I was used to manually editing the legends in matplotlib (https://stackoverflow.com/a/53324868/10226862), but I can't find a way to do this in plotly.

I've also tried to add annotations, but doing so also adds X and Y-axis.

Comment: Do you mind to tell us what do you want to show as legend?

Comment: I want to show the name and the value.

Comment: Name and value of every input?

Comment: Yes, once I can do that, I believe I can manipulate it to show only the inputs I'm interested in.

Comment: Maybe you can do it in the R language 'ggsunburt'. I referred to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926779/how-to-make-a-sunburst-plot-in-r-or-python).

Comment: @ArthurCoimbra How did ny suggestion work out for you?

Comment: @vestland It did the job! Thanks. I've been working on another solution with a scatter plot behind the sunburst where I hide every element except the legend. I will share it once I'm done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Displaying the outer values wouldn't make much sense since you've got three different colors for `Dinner`. But you *could* include the inner values in the sunburst diagram using annotations. You're right that this will trigger axes and backgrounds, but we can always remove those again. The snippet below will produce this figure:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.sunburst(df, path=['day', 'time'], values='total_bill')
D = df['day'].unique()

colors=['#EF553B',
         '#636EFA',
         '#00CC96',
         '#AB63FA',
         '#FFA15A',
         '#19D3F3',
         '#FF6692',
         '#B6E880',
         '#FF97FF',
         '#FECB52']

for i, m in enumerate(D):
    fig.add_annotation(dict(font=dict(color=colors[i],size=14),
                                        x=0.8,
                                        y=1-(i/10),
                                        showarrow=False,
                                        text=D[i],
                                        textangle=0,
                                        xanchor='left',
                                        xref="paper",
                                        yref="paper"))

fig.update_layout(
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
)

fig.update_xaxes(tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)'))
fig.update_yaxes(tickfont=dict(color='rgba(0,0,0,0)'))

fig.show()
```